# How to append multiple td in multiple tr in Javascript through appendChild?

Tags: javascript, appendchild

I'm making a calendar for my website. How can i append 7 td (7day each week) to 1 tr (week), then loop it for several times until the data finished?

I have tried this javascript codes

```js
var date = new Date(2019, 3, 1), y = date.getFullYear(), m = date.getMonth();
var firstDay = new Date(y, m, 1);
var lastDay = new Date(y, m + 1, 0);

var arrDayName = ['sun','mon','tue','wed','thu','fri','sat'];
var arrMonthName = ['jan','feb','mar','apr','may','jun','jul','aug','sep','oct','nov','dec'];
var arrIndoMonthName = ['Januari','Februari','Maret','April','Mei','Juni','Juli','Agustus','September','Oktober','November','Desember'];

var getFirstDayName = firstDay.toString().split(" ")[0].toLowerCase();
var getFirstMonName = firstDay.toString().split(" ")[1].toLowerCase();
var getFirstDateName = parseInt(firstDay.toString().split(" ")[2].toLowerCase());
var getFirstYearName = parseInt(firstDay.toString().split(" ")[3].toLowerCase());


var getLastDayName = lastDay.toString().split(" ")[0].toLowerCase();
var getLastMonName = lastDay.toString().split(" ")[1].toLowerCase();
var getLastDateName = parseInt(lastDay.toString().split(" ")[2].toLowerCase());
var getLastYearName = parseInt(lastDay.toString().split(" ")[3].toLowerCase());

// get first status
var firstStatus = '';
for (var i = 0; i < getLastDateName.length; i++) {
    if (arrDayName[i] == getFirstDayName) {
        firstStatus = i;
    }
}
// ------------------------------1. load older month

// ------------------------------2. load current month
for (var i = 1; i <= getLastDateName; i++) {
    // 1. fc day number
    var DOMfcDayNumber = document.createElement("div");
    DOMfcDayNumber.className = "fc-day-number";
    DOMfcDayNumber.innerHTML = i;

    // 2. fc-day-content inner
    var DOMfcDayContentInner = document.createElement("div");
    DOMfcDayContentInner.className = "fc-day-inner";
    DOMfcDayContentInner.innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
    // 3. fc-day-content wrapper 2
    var DOMfcDayContentWrapper = document.createElement("div");
    DOMfcDayContentWrapper.className = "fc-day-content";
    DOMfcDayContentWrapper.appendChild(DOMfcDayContentInner);

    // 4. fc-wrapper-inner wrapper 1 & 3
    var DOMwrpInnerContentInner = document.createElement("div");
    DOMwrpInnerContentInner.className = "fc-wrapper-inner";
    DOMwrpInnerContentInner.appendChild(DOMfcDayNumber);
    DOMwrpInnerContentInner.appendChild(DOMfcDayContentWrapper);

    // 5. fc-day wrapper 4
    var DOMfcDay = document.createElement("td");
    DOMfcDay.className = "fc-day";
    DOMfcDay.style.cssText = "padding:13px";
    DOMfcDay.appendChild(DOMwrpInnerContentInner);
    DOMfcDay.id = getLastYearName+"-"+getLastMonName+"-"+getLastDateName;

    if (i%8==0) {
        // 6. fc-week wrapper 5 <tr class="fc-week">
        var DOMfcWeek = document.createElement("tr");
        DOMfcWeek.className = "fc-week";
        DOMfcWeek.appendChild(DOMfcDay);
        document.getElementById("date-start").appendChild(DOMfcWeek);
    }else{
        document.getElementById("date-start").appendChild(DOMfcDay);
    }
}
```

```html
<table>
<tbody id="date-start">
    <tr class="fc-week-01">
        <td class="fc-day" id="2019-04-1">
            <div class="fc-wrapper-inner">
                <div class="fc-day-number">1</div>
                <div class="fc-day-content">
                    <div class="fc-day-inner">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="fc-day" id="2019-04-2">
            <div class="fc-wrapper-inner">
                <div class="fc-day-number">2</div>
                <div class="fc-day-content">
                    <div class="fc-day-inner">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    <tr>
    <tr class="fc-week-02">
        <td class="fc-day" id="2019-04-8">
            <div class="fc-wrapper-inner">
                <div class="fc-day-number">8</div>
                <div class="fc-day-content">
                    <div class="fc-day-inner">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="fc-day" id="2019-04-9">
            <div class="fc-wrapper-inner">
                <div class="fc-day-number">9</div>
                <div class="fc-day-content">
                    <div class="fc-day-inner">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        
    <tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

but confused about how to append tr to the parent for every 7 loop.
for now, the outcome is like this: [link](http://prntscr.com/nbbyg5)
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some minor mistakes in your code,

first you are not appending your td's in your tr's,

as seen in the below screenshot

[image]

2nd in your else condition change your code from

```
document.getElementById("date-start").appendChild(DOMfcDay);
```

to

```
document.getElementById("date-start").children[document.getElementById("date-start").children.length - 1].appendChild(DOMfcDay);
```

and lastly initialize your loop with `i = 0` and when assign the value of i do like this -> `DOMfcDayNumber.innerHTML = i + 1;` and check your condition like `(i%7==0)`,

below is the full example

```js
var date = new Date(2019, 3, 1), y = date.getFullYear(), m = date.getMonth();
var firstDay = new Date(y, m, 1);
var lastDay = new Date(y, m + 1, 0);

var arrDayName = ['sun','mon','tue','wed','thu','fri','sat'];
var arrMonthName = ['jan','feb','mar','apr','may','jun','jul','aug','sep','oct','nov','dec'];
var arrIndoMonthName = ['Januari','Februari','Maret','April','Mei','Juni','Juli','Agustus','September','Oktober','November','Desember'];

var getFirstDayName = firstDay.toString().split(" ")[0].toLowerCase();
var getFirstMonName = firstDay.toString().split(" ")[1].toLowerCase();
var getFirstDateName = parseInt(firstDay.toString().split(" ")[2].toLowerCase());
var getFirstYearName = parseInt(firstDay.toString().split(" ")[3].toLowerCase());


var getLastDayName = lastDay.toString().split(" ")[0].toLowerCase();
var getLastMonName = lastDay.toString().split(" ")[1].toLowerCase();
var getLastDateName = parseInt(lastDay.toString().split(" ")[2].toLowerCase());
var getLastYearName = parseInt(lastDay.toString().split(" ")[3].toLowerCase());

// get first status
var firstStatus = '';
for (var i = 0; i < getLastDateName.length; i++) {
    if (arrDayName[i] == getFirstDayName) {
        firstStatus = i;
    }
}
// ------------------------------1. load older month

// ------------------------------2. load current month
for (var i = 0; i <= getLastDateName; i++) {
    // 1. fc day number
    var DOMfcDayNumber = document.createElement("div");
    DOMfcDayNumber.className = "fc-day-number";
    DOMfcDayNumber.innerHTML = i + 1;

    // 2. fc-day-content inner
    var DOMfcDayContentInner = document.createElement("div");
    DOMfcDayContentInner.className = "fc-day-inner";
    DOMfcDayContentInner.innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
    // 3. fc-day-content wrapper 2
    var DOMfcDayContentWrapper = document.createElement("div");
    DOMfcDayContentWrapper.className = "fc-day-content";
    DOMfcDayContentWrapper.appendChild(DOMfcDayContentInner);

    // 4. fc-wrapper-inner wrapper 1 & 3
    var DOMwrpInnerContentInner = document.createElement("div");
    DOMwrpInnerContentInner.className = "fc-wrapper-inner";
    DOMwrpInnerContentInner.appendChild(DOMfcDayNumber);
    DOMwrpInnerContentInner.appendChild(DOMfcDayContentWrapper);

    // 5. fc-day wrapper 4
    var DOMfcDay = document.createElement("td");
    DOMfcDay.className = "fc-day";
    DOMfcDay.style.cssText = "padding:13px";
    DOMfcDay.appendChild(DOMwrpInnerContentInner);
    DOMfcDay.id = getLastYearName+"-"+getLastMonName+"-"+getLastDateName;

    if (i%7==0) {
        // 6. fc-week wrapper 5 <tr class="fc-week">
        var DOMfcWeek = document.createElement("tr");
        DOMfcWeek.className = "fc-week";
        DOMfcWeek.appendChild(DOMfcDay);
        document.getElementById("date-start").appendChild(DOMfcWeek);
    }else{
        document.getElementById("date-start").children[document.getElementById("date-start").children.length - 1].appendChild(DOMfcDay);
    }
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody id="date-start">
        <tr class="fc-week-01">
            <td class="fc-day" id="2019-04-1">
                <div class="fc-wrapper-inner">
                    <div class="fc-day-number">1</div>
                    <div class="fc-day-content">
                        <div class="fc-day-inner">&nbsp;</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="fc-day" id="2019-04-2">
                <div class="fc-wrapper-inner">
                    <div class="fc-day-number">2</div>
                    <div class="fc-day-content">
                        <div class="fc-day-inner">&nbsp;</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        <tr>
        <tr class="fc-week-02">
            <td class="fc-day" id="2019-04-8">
                <div class="fc-wrapper-inner">
                    <div class="fc-day-number">8</div>
                    <div class="fc-day-content">
                        <div class="fc-day-inner">&nbsp;</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="fc-day" id="2019-04-9">
                <div class="fc-wrapper-inner">
                    <div class="fc-day-number">9</div>
                    <div class="fc-day-content">
                        <div class="fc-day-inner">&nbsp;</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        <tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

hope this solves your problem.

Comment: oh my God.. Brilliant! i dont even think to do document.getElementById("date-start").children[document.getElementById("date-start").children.length - 1].appendChild(DOMfcDay);

Thanks for the help!

Comment: glad it solved your problem, can you please upvote my answer

Comment: maybe the execution time is slower than @jayarjo.. im choose this answer because of im in hurry to finish the project. and the codes are familiar with mine..

Comment: @AMTLS I agree, the execution time will be slower in my solution but, I think it's better not to change the code of the developer a lot to give him solution as it is easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You are generating invalid html there, sometimes inserting `TR` as the child of `TBODY`, sometimes directly `TD`. You should always wrap a row in `TR`, no matter if it has only one cell inside or many. Use [colspan](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp) attribute on a `TD` if you won't it to occupy more than one cell.

Also better generate the whole html as a string first and then insert it into the DOM at once. It will be faster and cleaner that way.

```js
var date = new Date(2019, 3, 1), y = date.getFullYear(), m = date.getMonth();
var firstDay = new Date(y, m, 1);
var lastDay = new Date(y, m + 1, 0);

var arrDayName = ['sun','mon','tue','wed','thu','fri','sat'];
var arrMonthName = ['jan','feb','mar','apr','may','jun','jul','aug','sep','oct','nov','dec'];
var arrIndoMonthName = ['Januari','Februari','Maret','April','Mei','Juni','Juli','Agustus','September','Oktober','November','Desember'];

var getFirstDayName = firstDay.toString().split(" ")[0].toLowerCase();
var getFirstMonName = firstDay.toString().split(" ")[1].toLowerCase();
var getFirstDateName = parseInt(firstDay.toString().split(" ")[2].toLowerCase());
var getFirstYearName = parseInt(firstDay.toString().split(" ")[3].toLowerCase());


var getLastDayName = lastDay.toString().split(" ")[0].toLowerCase();
var getLastMonName = lastDay.toString().split(" ")[1].toLowerCase();
var getLastDateName = parseInt(lastDay.toString().split(" ")[2].toLowerCase());
var getLastYearName = parseInt(lastDay.toString().split(" ")[3].toLowerCase());

// get first status
var firstStatus = '';
for (var i = 0; i < getLastDateName.length; i++) {
    if (arrDayName[i] == getFirstDayName) {
        firstStatus = i;
    }
}

var html = '';
var tr = '';

for (var i = 1; i <= getLastDateName; i++) {
    var tdId = getLastYearName+"-"+getLastMonName+"-"+getLastDateName;
    var td = '<div class="fc-wrapper-inner"><div class="fc-day-number">'+i+'<div class="fc-day-content"><div class="fc-day-inner">&nbsp;</div></div></div>';
    
    tr += '<td id="'+tdId+'" class="fc-day" style="padding:13px">'+td+'</td>';

    if (i%7==0) {
      html += '<tr class="fc-week">'+tr+'</tr>';
      tr = '';
    }
}

html += '<tr class="fc-week">'+tr+'</tr>';

document.getElementById('date-start').innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<table id="date-start">
</table>
```

Comment: actually, that is what i ask before.. the problem is about how to handle the TR after loop :)

Comment: this is very efficient and faster.. i will think to use this method in the next chance.. thanks for the example!